# Why isn't my RangeValidator working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, validation, controls

I succesfully used a validator more than once,but after some programming my validators are not working.Maybe is something i don't know about defining 2 validators for the same control, but it doesn't work for one validator in a control either.Here are 2 examples of my code:

Example 1: one required field validator and one "maximum value" validator for username:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="UsernameRequiredValidator" runat="server"
                                  ControlToValidate="UserNameTextbox" ForeColor="red"
                                  Display="Dynamic"  ErrorMessage="Required" />

<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UsernameTextbox"  MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="20"  ForeColor="red"  
    Display="Dynamic"   ErrorMessage="Name must contain maximum 20 characters"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Example 2: one "maximum value" validator for roadaddress(string):

```
 <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator9" runat="server" MaximumValue="50"  ForeColor="red"
          ErrorMessage="Road Address must contain maxmum 50 characters" ControlToValidate="RoadAddressTextbox"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

I am thinking that the problem is maybe in the display property or in the causesvalidation property which i don't use...

Comment: no AJAX no UpdatePanel..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not what the `RangeValidator` is used for. The `RangeValidator` is intended to check input to make sure it's within a certain range, i.e. to make sure that a number is between 1 and 5, that a date is within a certain range, etc.

What you need is a `RegularExpressionValidator`:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="UserNameTextbox"
    ErrorMessage="Username must be between 1 and 50 characters" 
    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,50}">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**EDIT:** Updated expression to `^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,50}`

Answer (score 3):

RangeValidators don't validate the number of characters in the input, they "[Check whether the value of an input control is within a specified range of values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx)."

You can actually do this without a Validator, by setting the `MaxLength` property on the text box which would limit the number of characters entered into it.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserNameTextbox" MaxLength="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```